# Insert statement, if variable is not blank

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert, null

I am using VB.net to write some values to my dB.

However I am having issues with syntax of the below code.

What I need to do is to run the SQL INSERT statement, providing that the value being passed for `ChargeCode` is not blank.

```
INSERT INTO Daisy_March2014 (ChargeCode,Peak,OffPeak,Weekend,Setup,MinimumCharge)
VALUES ('" + ComboBox1.Text + "','" + ComboBox2.Text + "','" + ComboBox3.Text + "','" + ComboBox4.Text + "','" + ComboBox5.Text + "','" + ComboBox6.Text + "')
SELECT WHERE 'ChargeCode' IS NOT NULL;
```

Can this be done using SQL?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value then procede with sql.

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Combobox1.Text) Then
  Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Daisy_March2014 " &  
      "(ChargeCode,Peak,OffPeak,Weekend,Setup,MinimumCharge)" &
      "VALUES ('" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & ComboBox2.Text & "','" & ComboBox3.Text &
      "','" &  ComboBox4.Text & "','" & ComboBox5.Text & "','" & ComboBox6.Text & "')"
End If
```

You should also look into Parameterized queries for protection against sql injection.